# Making a Non-nullable value type nullable

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, non-nullable

I have a simple struct that has limited use. The struct is created in a method that calls the data from the database. If there is no data returned from the database I want to be able to return a null, but Visual Studio complains, Cannot convert null to PackageName.StructName because it is a non-nullable value type.

How can I make it nullable?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want to look into the [`Nullable<T>`](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2004/05/27/143221.aspx) value type.

Comment: I used this and it still complains

Answer (score 13):

```
public struct Something
{
    //...
}

public static Something GetSomethingSomehow()
{
    Something? data = MaybeGetSomethingFrom(theDatabase);
    bool questionMarkMeansNullable = (data == null);
    return data ?? Something.DefaultValue;
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand, this code does not return null as Malfist wants to.

Comment: IIRC, it was intended as an illustration of the use of nullable types, since the poster didn't seem to understand exactly what they were.

Comment: `default(Something)` may have been a better default return value in the event that no value exists.

Answer (score 8):

The definition for a `Nullable<T>` struct is:

```
struct Nullable<T>
{
    public bool HasValue;
    public T Value;
}
```

It is created in this manner:

```
Nullable<PackageName.StructName> nullableStruct = new Nullable<PackageName.StructName>(params);
```

You can shortcut this mess by simply typing:

```
PackageName.StructName? nullableStruct  = new PackageName.StructName(params);
```

See: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

[`Nullable<T>`](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2004/05/27/143221.aspx) is a wrapper class that creates a nullable version of the type T. You can also use the syntax T? (e.g. int?) to represent the nullable version of type T.

Comment: Calling `Nullable<T>` a "wrapper class" is incorrect: is a `struct`, not a `class`, so it has value-type semantics, not reference-type semantics. It _does_ have some special _compiler magic_ though, in that even though `Nullable<T>` is a `struct`, it cannot be used as a generic type argument when the generic type parameter has a `T : struct` constraint, nor can `Nullable<T>` be used _as_ `T` in another `Nullable<T>`, so `Nullable<Nullable<Int32>>` won't compile either.

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in *shortcuts* for the `Nullable<T>` struct, by simply adding `?` to the declaration:

```
int? x = null;

if (x == null) { ... }
```

Just the same for any other type, struct, etc.

```
MyStruct? myNullableStruct = new MyStruct(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make something nullable for example like this:

```
// Create the nullable object.
int? value = new int?();

// Check for if the object is null.
if(value == null)
{
    // Your code goes here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **default** as an alternative

```
public struct VelocityRange
{
    private double myLowerVelocityLimit;
    private double myUpperVelocityLimit;
}
```

VelocityRange velocityRange = **default**(VelocityRange);

Comment: The `default(T)` of a value-type `T` is its zero-byte representation, which may be significant, especially when dealing with integer value-types, for example `default(Int32) == 0` - for that reason I never recommend using `default` as a stand-in for "null".