# Get error "Cannot convert to null 'Point' because it is a non-nullable value type."

Tags: c#, non-nullable

Sorry advance for such a simple question ( I have googled but I am stumped, new to programming)

sample code below

```
  public Point GetRandomWalkableLocationInRoom(Rectangle room)
    {
        if (DoesRoomHaveWalkableSpace(room))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                int x = Game.Random.Next(1, room.Width - 2) + room.X;
                int y = Game.Random.Next(1, room.Height - 2) + room.Y;
                if (IsWalkable(x, y))
                {
                    return new Point(x, y);
                }
            }
        }


        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a Non-nullable value type nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596003/making-a-non-nullable-value-type-nullable)

Comment: Just change the return type of your method to `Point?`.  Read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/).

Comment: You can't return null from this method. Error is here :  return null;     You should always return new Point();    or throw exception in case of error.   But you can't return null because there is no way to convert null to Point()

Comment: Thanks, I have entered  new Point(); that has done the trick! stupid me!

Comment: It seems like returning `new Point();` will introduce a bug.  Is it really valid to return 0, 0 if you can't find a walkable point?

Comment: @Muzzasa be careful, it made your code able to build, but it doesn't necessarily mean that it is fixed

Answer (score 4):

In the case where DoesRoomHaveWalkableSpace(room) is false, either throw an exception (if that fits your implementation), or return some default value, like 'new Point(double.NaN, double.NaN)' or 'new Point(null, null)'.

Comment: Alternatively, make the method return a `Point?`.

Comment: I  used a  default value 'return new Point();' that has done the trick! 
thanks!